# AOP not working in the interface method implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have a situation where I have a default method which is calling another method of the same interface.

```
public interface Test {

    default Boolean isValidObject(String A) {
      ComplexObject B= new  ComplexObject();
      SomeObject SomeObject= validate(A, B);
      return SomeObject.isValid();
    }

    SomeObject validate(String A, ComplexObject b);
}
```

If I put the point referring to `isValidObject`, then it is working fine. However if the point cut is referring to `validate` then that is now working.

Pointcut that is not working

```
@After("execution(fullqualifiedSomeObject com.a.b.c.Test+.validate(..))")
```

Moreover, a marker is visible on the left having message. "3 Spring AOP marker at this line"

Please share thoughts.

Comment: Test+.validate(..) shouldn't that be Test.validate(..) ?

Comment: why not create annotations to mark your methods to which you want to apply aop? the way you work now, you'll have to update your aop specific code each time you want to change the list of methods on which you want it to run, even if they 're all supposed to do the exact same.

Comment: @Stultuske, Need that AOP at all implementation. However, Test.validate(..) is now working.

Comment: @ Stultuske, Creating custom annotation is also not working. It  is showing me marker with message "3 Spring AOP marker at this line"

Comment: what exactly is it now, is it working or not? and without seeing the codechanges you made, it's hard to guess what causes it to fail

Comment: It is not possible to show you complete code (NDA). But please let me know, I'll provide you the details you want.

Comment: it might be failing because you are not pointing to an actual implementation, but  to a declaration in an interface (not sure though). how exactly did you define your pointcut, and what is the exact message about those markers?

Comment: Spring AOP works with proxies. AOP will only be applied, due to proxies, on method calls going into the object, when making internal method calls (like you are doing) they don't pass through the proxy and as such don't have AOP applied.

Comment: @Stultuske: Your comments are just irritating a Spring AOP newbie. `Test+` is just fine because it also includes all subclasses. Furthermore, it is not necessary to combine AOP with marker annotations if there are other ways to determine the weaving targets. I even prefer not to use marker annotations. Ideally, the core developer should not even need to know about the aspect, because otherwise she can forget to add tons of annotations for different aspects and the aspects do not kick in. M. Deinum's answer is helpful, I think the OP should concentrate on that one.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you add your comment as answer so that I can accept it for others reference. Very sorry for too late message.